# does Moles add a 01, 02 etc to Moletypes that are attached to partial classes?

Tags: moles

I'm using Moles for mocking. The other day I built a Moles assembly for a reference that has many partial classes in it. The generated Moles assembly seems to have two classes that are built out of the one class:

```
FileSendDataAccess
```

becomes

```
MFileSendDataAccess  MFileSendDataAccess01
```

Is this by design or a bug? It's very confusing since I now have two classes to use to access the one class. Using Moles 0.93.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, according to Peli: Moles will add 01 etc to a class name when there are two classes in your references that have the same name.

> Partial classes are a syntatic sugar,
>   C# generates a type of them. 
>   Moles adds numbers ot [sic] type names when there are name clashing between
>   types. 
>   Maybe you have 2 FileSendDataAccess type in your
>   assembly? You can use 
>   Reflector to easily find out.

**However**: if the classes have the same name but different namespaces they will still get the 01 02 stuff. **This is a bug** that is still happening as of 0.94.